# Detect inside a custom query the kind of post type to assign custom classes

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, customization

I have created the following query in order to get several post types in a custom page, which so far works:

```
<?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => array('things', 'people', 'post'),
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
            );

            $query = new WP_Query( $args );
            $postcount = 0;
        ?>

        <?php if ($query->have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>

             <?php the_title( '', '', true ); ?>

        <?php $count++; // Increase the count by 1 ?>       
        <?php endwhile; endif; // END the Wordpress Loop ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I want to have each post type with a class, or several classes. If it is a people custom post type, add the class people around. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`post_class` function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) will do this for you automatically within the loop:

```
<div <?php post_class(); ?>>
```

which will add some combination of these classes:

- .post-[id]
- .[post-type]
- .type-[post-type]
- .status-[post-status]
- .format-[post-format] (default to 'standard')
- .post-password-required
- .post-password-protected
- .has-post-thumbnail
- .sticky
- .hentry (hAtom microformat pages)
- .[taxonomy]-[taxonomy-slug] (includes category)
- .tag-[tag-name]

You can also get just the post type within the loop via the [`get_post_type`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type/) function:

```
<?php echo get_post_type(); ?>
```